# IIS SSL Issues Under Heavy Website Load -- Non-SSL Works Fine

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

My IIS 7.5 web server farm (2xWindows 2008 R2 physical servers using Network Load Balancing) is experiencing heavy server use and SSL/TLS requests to port 443 are timing out on what appears to be the TLS negotiation (500+ Get Requests/sec with over 20K Current Connections).

Despite the heavy load, the performance of the server hardware is fine--less than 20% processor utilization, 75% of memory still available, and virtually no processor queuing. Additionally, the bandwidth utilization is fine as well. However, during this heavy usage event, my websites stopped responding to SSL-based (https) requests and clients were unable to negotiate a TLS connection. During this same time, requests using http to the same websites were working fine and the websites were very responsive (I disabled the IIS rewrite rule from http to https). The problem may have gone away after I uninstalled my CA issued certificate and reinstalled the same one and then restarted all web services however I can't say for sure that this corrected it because I also stopped forcing the use of SSL.

In troubleshooting, the only thing I see is that my Windows event logs are filled with Event ID: 36887, which seems to be related to SSL but the meaning of the error is vague to me. This is the description of the error message:

"This error message indicates the computer received an SSL fatal alert message from the server ( It is not a bug in the Schannel or the application that uses Schannel). Sometimes is caused by the installation of third party web browser (other than Internet Explorer)."

There are hundreds of entries per minute corresponding to the time of the performance issues. After this occurred, I was told to enable the CAPI2 log but since the issue is not occurring now, I only see informational messages in this log.

What would cause this problem with TLS unable to negotiate a connection under a heavy load in my networked balanced web farm and how I can prevent this from occurring again?

Comment: It sounds more like a question for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/). Be sure to include the details from an event log entry. Also, does anything in [Schannel Error Codes for TLS and SSL Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/schannel-error-codes-for-tls-and-ssl-alerts?redirectedfrom=MSDN) seem relevant?

Comment: It has little to do with programming, as TLS connections are handled by the relevant Windows components. When in doubt, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: are you using a self-signed certificate or trusted CA?

Comment: The site is using a trusted CA.

Comment: in opinion this happens because of the supported TLS version is not matched, please check the registry key value for EventLogging, under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL.